# Treatment of Every Element as a Set

Tags: set-theory

Can we treat every element of every set as a Set or Subset. We know that there are sets of sets like Set of all lines in a Plane. In this set every element (line) is a Set of points. Can we treat points as sets which contains nothing. In other words If N is Set of all Natural Numbers then can it be so that Every Natural number is an Empty Set ?

Comment: Others will likely say more than the following (and know more than I do), but briefly there are set theories that allow for [urelements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement), which are mathematical objects that can be members of sets without being a set. However, I suspect that even in these set theories, objects as "concrete" as the points on a line or the natural numbers would NOT be urelements.

Comment: Every natural number is the set of its predecessors. $0=\emptyset$, $1 = \{0\} = \{\emptyset\}$, $2= \{0,1\}= \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ and so on. Points in the plane are pairs of real numbers. (A pair is a special type of set, see Pairing Axiom). A real "is" a pair of sets of rational numbers (using the Dedekind model) and a rational number is a pair of integers. And so on. We can build all standard objects in "common maths" this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question, and I'm glad you asked. It is standard in most set theories to treat all objects as sets, or set-like objects such as [classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory)) or [semisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiset). Such as in the cases of [ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) and [NBG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory) (two of the most prevalent set theories).

However, as Dave L. Renfro points out, some set theories allow for the existence of [urelements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement), which are members of sets but are not sets themselves.

**Onto your question:**

> If $\mathbb{N}$ is set of all natural numbers, then can it be so that every natural number is an empty set?

The short answer is *no*. If all natural numbers were the empty set, then by the [Axiom of Extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality) (perhaps the most accepted axiom), they would all be equal, which is certainly not a property we would like to have.

However, it *is* standard to treat the natural numbers as sets. The most common approach is called the [Von Neumann ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals) defined as follows:

$$0 := \{\}$$
$$n+1 := n\cup\{n\}.$$

So in this sense, $5=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. This aproach is nice, because it satisfies that the $n^{th}$ natural number contains $n$ distinct elements. This is not the only approach however. Other examples include the [Zermelo ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Zermelo_ordinals), where

$$0  := \{\}$$
$$n+1  := \{n\}.$$

So, $5=\{4\}$. This approach also has a nice property. Namely, that when treated as a [rooted identity tree](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RootedTree.html), the $n^{th}$ natural number has $n$ nodes.